# Battery down over night?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I only found a question where the cause of this problem was the exchange service. 
But in my case the battery went down from 80 to 9% over night, with 55% consumed by *Android OS*.
What are the services that run under that name that could cause 3:30h of CPU time?

[image]